# str.replace issue

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to get the following code working, it should remove vowels from a user-inputted string of text.

```
def isVowel(text):
    if text in ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"):
        return True

def withoutVowels(text):
    for char in text:
        if(isVowel == True):
            text = text.replace(char, "")
    return text
```

The isVowel function is working fine, however it does not seem to evaluate correctly when I use it, why is this?

Comment: What is an example of when it doesn't work correctly?

Comment: Side note: what `withoutVowels()` does is better done with `import re; without_vowles = re.sub('[aeiou]', '', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)` or `re.sub('[aeiouAEIOU]', '', text)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if (isVowel == True):
```

should be

```
if isVowel(char):
```

`isVowel` is a function object. `isVowel == True` will always be False.

---

Note that you could also do this, faster and more simply with [str.translate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate).

```
In [90]: 'Abracadabra'.translate(None, 'aeiouAEIOU')
Out[90]: 'brcdbr'
```

or, (as EOL points out) using regex:

```
In [93]: import re
In [95]: re.sub(r'(?i)[aeiou]', '', 'Abracadabra')
Out[95]: 'brcdbr'
```

However, `str.translate` is faster in this case:

```
In [94]: %timeit 'Abracadabra'.translate(None, 'aeiouAEIOU')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 316 ns per loop
In [96]: %timeit re.sub(r'(?i)[aeiou]', '', 'Abracadabra')
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.26 us per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one line, because Python is awesome:

```
def withoutVowels(text):
    return "".join(c for c in text if c not in "aeiouAEIOU")
```