# Loop to remove characters from list not working

Tags: python, list, for-loop, python-3.x

I have a list of punctuation that I want the loop to remove from a user inputted sentence, and it seems to ignore multiple punctuation in a row?

```
punctuation = ['(', ')', '?', ':', ';', ',', '.', '!', '/', '"', "'"]
usr_str=input('Type in a line of text: ')

#Convert to list
usr_list= list(usr_str)

#Checks if each item in list is punctuation, and removes ones that are
for char in usr_list:
    if char in punctuation:
        usr_list.remove(char)

#Prints resulting string
print(''.join(usr_list))
```

Now this works for:

```
This is an example string, which works fine!
```

Which prints:

```
This is an example string which works fine
```

However, something like this:

```
Testing!!!!, )
```

Gives:

```
Testing!!
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: The problem is that the iterator isn't being moved back to check the character that takes the place of the one removed. However, you really should be using a cleaner approach such as a RegEx.

Comment: Ah okay Spencer that makes sense, and I am reasonably new at Python, so I will do some looking into Regular Expressions.  Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want to get into a RegEx I'd also recommend @Soon's answer for `string.translate`.

Comment: See [Loop “Forgets” to Remove Some Items](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17299581/1730674) also [str.replace issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15456639/1730674) and [Remove specific characters from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19458344/1730674)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're changing the list *while* you're iterating over it.  Never a good idea.

One way to get it to work is to iterate over a copy of the list:

```
for char in usr_list[:]:  # this is the only part that changed; add [:] to make a copy
    if char in punctuation:
        usr_list.remove(char)
```

With more experience, you'll probably use a "list comprehension" instead:

```
usr_list = [char for char in usr_list if char not in punctuation]
```

You'll probably get other answers using `filter()` or regular expressions or ... too.  But keep it simple at first :-)

Another way is to make two different lists.  Say your input list is `input_list`.  Then:

```
no_punc = []
for char in usr_list:
    if char not in punctuation:
        no_punc.append(char)
```

And note that there's really no need to use an input *list* in this way either.  You could iterate directly over your `usr_str` instead.

Comment: Thanks so much Tim, this seems like a straightforward fix, and I understand both ways.  My assignment specifies using a loop, so the first way will have to be what I use, but its nice to know there are simpler ways!

Comment: Using `[:]` may be too obscure, though, so I just added another way - it will be even more obvious to you ;-)  And added another way getting rid of one of the lists.

Answer (score 2):

This could be done using [`str.translate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) method:

```
In [10]: 'Testing!!!!, )'.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
Out[10]: 'Testing '
```